# Custom ListView not returning all checked items

Tags: android

i want to make a button that when clicked, all items in a custom ListView get checked. the ListView consists of 3 TextView and 1 CkeckBox. the adapter is as:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View v = convertView;
           if (v == null) {
               LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               v = vi.inflate(id, null);
           }

           final Item o = items.get(position);
           if (o != null) {
                   TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                   TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                   TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
                   final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                   checkBox1.setTag(o.getPath());
                   checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                         int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                         items.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) buttonView ;
                      if(cb.isChecked()){
                          if(!FileChooser1.clickedItems.contains(o.getPath())){
                              FileChooser1.clickedItems.add(o.getPath());
                          }
                      }else{                              
                          FileChooser1.clickedItems.remove(o.getPath());

                      }

                    }
                });
                   checkBox1.setTag(position);

                    ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_Icon1);
                    String uri = "drawable/" + o.getImage();
                    int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
                    Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                    imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);

                   if(t1!=null)
                    t1.setText(o.getName());
                   if(t2!=null)
                        t2.setText(o.getData());
                   if(t3!=null)
                        t3.setText(o.getDate());
                   if(o.getImage().equals("directory_up")){
                       checkBox1.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                   }else{
                       checkBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
                   if(someBoolean == true)
                   {
                   checkBox1.setChecked(true);// here i set the checkbox to true for all items  
                   }


           }
           return v;               
   }     
}
```

FileChooser1.clickedItems is an ArrayList which holds all clicked items, the problem is that only items which are seen on the screen are added to the ArrayList, i mean for example when i scroll to bottom of the phone screen, only those items which are seen on the screen are added to the list. for example i have 20 items, at first when i open activity it adds only 8 first items to the ArrayList and if i scroll down further, then those items which appear at the bottom will be added to arraylist, isn't there anyway to add all items to the List without scrolling? many thanks

Comment: your `items` object must be static

Comment: thanks but it didn't work for static too

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button to check all the items in a ListView, here is the recipe:

Add a boolean `inFileChooser` with getters and setters to your `Item` class:

```
private boolean mInFileChooser;

public boolean isInFileChooser() {
    return mIsInFileChooser;
}

public void setInFileChooser(boolean inFileChooser) {
    mInFileChooser = inFileChooser;
    if (inFileChooser) {
        FileChooser1.clickedItems.add(getPath());
    } else {                              
        FileChooser1.clickedItems.remove(getPath());
    }
}
```

When you create the view in the adapter, you would call:

```
checkbox1.setChecked(o.isInFileChooser());
```

In MVC terms, this is where your *View* gets its initial value from the *Model*

Do this *before* you set your OnCheckedChangedListener, so you don't trigger it.

Then set your OnCheckedChangedListener. In your OnCheckedChangedListener.onCheckChanged, you call:

```
o.setInFileChooser(isChecked);
```

In MVC terms, this is where the *Controller* (OnCheckedChangedListener) transfers the change in the *View* to the *Model*.

The Button will get an OnClickListener that will iterate through all the items in the ListView adapter, set `isInFileChooser(true)` on them, and tell the adapter that the model has been changed and it's time to update the ListView.

For example, have a method on your adapter list this:

```
public void selectAllItems() {

    for (Item item : items) {
        item.setInFileChooser(true);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // acccess the adapter here
        adapter.selectAllItems();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, i am aware that with scrolling the items are added to ArrayList, i just want to add all items to the arraylist and not only those which are seen on the screen